# Rational numbers in Python

Tags: python, fractions

I need to compute a recursive sequence of numbers. In the formula, I need to compute B(r) where B(x) is a polynomial with rational coefficients (i.e fractions) and r is a rational number. My code is

```
def B(x):
    return x**2-x+1/6
```

However, when I plug r in, I get a floating number, not a rational number. This is expected.

I have several polynomials like this and my formula involves addition/subtraction with these numbers. How can I return the final result as a rational number?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) class.

Comment: Try importing math
[Link to the library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

Comment: The `1/6` part of the expression will have a floating point result, so even if you use a `fractions.Fraction` for `r`, the result will be floating point. You might use `fractions.Fraction(1,6)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module is really helpful.

```py
from fractions import Fraction
def B(x):
    x = Fraction(x)
    return x**2-x + Fraction(1,6)
```

[**Try It Online**](https://tio.run/##VU/LCsIwEDw3X7G3JH2gteBB8GAOfoUgxSYaaJOyRohfH9PG@tjDDjvDzLDj092saUInFYiz7Tvm@Y5AHJTugQZ8nm8qX9SrbVBoB1DYXpy25g56GC06OL4JMkfM9szD/sNHhmR/YVB8RRqDKQ8jauMYPSgnkZZAT27aQiqLknISATRoA9iaq2R1CfV66kk2wTRfPOkHzTlJ2oJiamoo/7mrRIQX)

Basically, `x**2-x` doesn't have division, it doesn't need to be a `Fraction`. Because `1/6` would become a floating point number, use `Fraction('1/6')` or `Fraction(1,6)`. Math with a `Fraction` input will return a `Fraction`. Putting `x = Fraction(x)` at the top allows for fractional inputs.

Comment: Thanks! It worked (so far!)

My understanding from reading the comments is that every time there is a fraction, I need to use Fraction('a/b'). I tested some small cases and it worked. 

Is there a similar class to work with a general algebraic number field like Q(i) or Q(root of 2)?

Comment: @tungprime Yes, but you might have to do a bit more research. Python has built-ins for imaginaries. Use `1j` for *i*. For fields try reading [here](https://www.howtobuildsoftware.com/index.php/how-do/Npg/python-sympy-representing-rings-of-algebraic-integers). You could also use [SageMath](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SageMath)

Comment: I tested more cases and realized that it did not work. Could you try B(1/3) please. The answer should be (-1, 18) but the output answer is Fraction(-1501199875790165, 27021597764222976).

Comment: @tungprime Put `x=Fraction(x)` at the top of the function. Then, pass your parameter as a string, or as a `Fraction`. I updated the code I provided to handle your case.

Comment: @tungprime That's because your input 1/3 is already bad.

Comment: @mbomb007 and superb rain:  Ah, I got it. Thanks! I have one additional question. If I convert 1/3 into a string by str(1/3) then it does not work. It only works if I write x='1/3'. 

Now, my problem is that I need to run a for loop. For simply, let say I want to compute B(1/5)+B(2/5)+B(3/5)+B(4/5). As I cannot convert these numbers into strings by the str method, what could I do to solve this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: @tungprime Use `B(Fraction(a,b))` where `a` is the numerator, and `b` is the denominator. Consider reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) that is linked in my question. If my answer helped, consider marking it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: If the numbers come from elsewhere and are already decimals, then you'll have to convert the rest of your code to use `Fraction()`

Answer (score -1):

Since everyone keeps suggesting to use `fractions.Fraction` for some reason, I'm going to put this in here:

** FLOATS ARE RATIONAL **

As a matter of fact, the class `numbers.Rational` provides a default for the numerator/denominator of floats. You can use `float.as_integer_ratio()` to get the exact numerator/denominator representation.

Now of course, the reason for this is the limited precision of floats requires all irrationals are truncated to rationals. So if it is exact computations you are after, then yes, go with `fractions.Fraction`.

Comment: This isn't really helpful. For `1/6` (used in the question), `print(float.as_integer_ratio(1/6))` returns `(6004799503160661, 36028797018963968)`. That's because 1/6 is an infinite decimal (in binary).

Comment: What does "limited precision of floats requires all irrationals are truncated to rationals" mean?

Comment: @superbrain Even some rationals are truncated, like 1/3. So he's not quite right. I think he means that rationals are truncated to be finite, rather than irrationals.

Comment: @mbomb007 OP clearly has the misconception that floats are irrationals. All floats are rationals. If we define being "helpful" as "just give what OP wants" then sure by that definition this post is not helpful. But the purpose of this post is to clear up a misconception from OP. Maybe checking out the documentation of the standard lib `numbers.Rationals` would give you dome ideas.

Comment: @superbrain got an extra "are" in there. What I meant is all irrationals are truncated to a rational number when expressed as a floating point because of the limited precision. Also yes, the converse is not true (my statement that irrationals are truncated is still correct): not all rationals can be expressed perfectly as a floating point as mbomb007 has suggested.

Comment: Ok, I think I get your point, now, though still find "truncated to rationals" a weird/unclear phrase. [Not even Google has heard of that](https://www.google.com/search?q="truncated+to+rationals") :-)

Comment: @superbrain well since irrational numbers have non-repeating and infinitely-many digits - the conversion to rationals could be seen as if you are striping it off its digits - hence the word truncation.

Comment: The semantics of the Scheme programming language provides a better insight IMO: the numbers are divided into exact and inexact ones (a division orthogonal to the division between the mathematical domains). A hardware float is an inexact real number. It doesn't make much sense to ask whether such a number is rational or not because however small the inexactness is, it can still be an irrational or a rational number. Only for exact numbers, one can sensibly ask whether they are rational or irrational.